# Using Media Queries To Only Include JS Files On Mobile

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

I am trying to use the media attribute to only link my javascript files on to mobile devices, not on desktop ones.

Here's my link tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" media="screen and (max-width : 850px)" src="mobile.js"></script>
```

But this isn't working, it links to JS to everything.

How do I only link a JS file if it meets those query conditions?

If I can't how do I only run JS if it is on mobile?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about using javascript for that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if (screen.width < 980) { 

    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="mobile.js"></script>');  
 } 

</script>
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Just didn't know if there was a way to specify it in HTML. Thanks!

Comment: @Josh be warned, this does not work on all mobile devices, such as the Samsung Galaxy II running Android < 3.

Comment: @jshthornton: why doesn't it work? All this seems pretty standard compliant; what part fails?

Comment: @frenchie It is a two stage issue.
1. Is that document.write is dodgy at the best of times 2. screen.width gets the incorrect size on that device, even with the correct viewport

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this:

1. Have all of your scripts on the page already and invoke them when the breakpoints are triggered
2. Load your scripts only when they are needed, once a breakpoint is met

Either way, you will need this:

[enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/)

This will allow you to add media queries callbacks for js.

Comment: The idea is not to add more overhead on mobile devices. requirejs = 84.6k not very many js files are even half that big.

Comment: @CelticParser There will always be more overhead, as what ever solution is implemented will have a size... therefore overhead. You'd have to weigh up if the added overhead of bespoke logic or enquire.js is greater than the saved overhead of having all of the scripts in the page already.

Comment: I'd rather conditionally load ( and do ) with a couple of lines of JavaScript that's a few hundred bytes over something that's nearly a Meg. esp. When it comes to UX for mobile users.

Comment: I agree. I would prefer to do that too. But the couple of lines doesn't cover a lot of cases. Such as a common use case of a user rotating their devices. Therefore you have loaded in script A, but in reality they need script B.

Comment: Then add a listener that's only a dozen more charachters to a page. The point is "mobile first" which means User first. In other words, be considerate to those who are on limited bandwidth, not making yourself and other lazy developers "lives easier". Learn the trade and stop dumping unnecessary assets that are bigger than the page it's self.

Comment: Yeah... no... The point of using a library is to cater to handling edge cases, and ensuring browser compatibility. By the time you have written your own bespoke, and handled those you are probably above enquire's 0.8kb size.

Answer (score 0):

Light weight and works everywhere w/o the overhead.

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 900) {   // scripts }
```