# Is there any way to enable website java script only in mobile browsers, not in desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

My website is `www.timepassraja.com`, I have a script that will help to reduce the Google adsense search result page width, so if I use this script, search result page width is changing in mobile and laptop/desktop. Now I want know is there any way to enable this width decreasing script in only mobile/tablet devices browser? I don't want effect this script in desktop/laptop device browser.

Script

```
try{
  document.getElementsByName('googleSearchFrame')[0].width=500;
}catch(e){}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser

Comment: Take a look here to:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946403/using-media-queries-to-only-include-js-files-on-mobile

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser